# Stream Analytics CollectTop(x) does not return x events

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Has anyone used CollectTop in stream analytics?  I followed the example here and pretty much used the exact same sample code:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/collecttop-azure-stream-analytics

SELECT
    customerID,
    CollectTop(2) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp desc) as top1
FROM testinput
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(day, 7), customerid
having Value = 'Processed'

Data sample (not exactly the same as actual data, simplified but the timestamps are same as actual):
[
  {
    "Value": "Processed",
    "CustomerId": "524",
    "OrderId": "545",     
    "Timestamp": "2018-02-16T19:44:35.9002665Z"
    },
  {
    "Value": "Processed",
    "CustomerId": "524",
    "OrderId": "545",     
    "Timestamp": "2018-02-17T19:44:35.9002665Z"
    },
  {
    "Value": "Processed",
    "CustomerId": "524",
    "OrderId": "545",     
    "Timestamp": "2018-02-18T19:44:35.9002665Z"
    }
]

I am trying to collect top 2 events but when I run the query it returns all events but I only want 2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Its looks like the CollectTop(x) is working. The following is a screen snippet for your test case sample:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should not be happening unless timestamp column has the same value for all input events. Please provide data sample illustrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I have edited original post to include sample data.  To answer your question, yes the timestamps are all different.  But even if they are the same, shouldnt it just return 2?  I have tried changing the tumblingWindow but still returning all events.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies it was a mistake on my end I missed an alias.

Thanks for the help everyone.